# Springboot + JSP + Spring Security: Failed to configure a DataSource

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm new using springboot and I've been triying to configure a project with it and spring security, but unfortunately I'm not able to run it. I'm getting the next error :

nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

I've been looking for a solution but I can't find anything that fit in my project. 
Please, any idea?
You can see the project here :

[Proyect](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kuJzSo_ayUlRXeOFZjQzavoKrf9i1Bgi)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In application.properties, Change

```
app.datasource.jdbc-url
app.datasource.username
app.datasource.password
app.datasource.driver-class-name
```

To

```
spring.datasource.url
spring.datasource.username
spring.datasource.password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name
```

Comment: Ok, It's working but it is not showing the custom login page and either is doing the loging with valid credentails :S

Comment: "is not showing the custom login"?  What custom login are you expecting?